# How to Display API data stored in state

Tags: reactjs, use-state

Am new to react and am tying to display data from an API but can't figure out where am going wrong.

```
const [all,setAll]=React.useState([])

React.useEffect(()=>{ 
        fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=<key>')
        .then(data=>{
           return data.json()
        }).then(completedata=>{
            
            setAll(completedata.results)
           
        })
        
    },[])

    return(
        <div id="movie-card">
            <img src={all.poster_path} alt={all.original_title}/>
            <h3>{all.original_title}</h3>
            <span> Ratings:{all.vote_average}</span>
            <h4>{all.release_date}</h4>
        </div>
    )
 }
```

Comment: You have initialized your state with an array, and there is no check if your data exists before using it inside the HTML template.

Comment: how should i initialize my state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have mapped through the 'all' array here inorder to to display each individual object results

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your useEffect:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{ 
  fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=<key>')
   .then(data=>{
     return data.json()
   }).then(completedata => { 
      setAll(completedata)
  })
},[])
```

Comment: okay and if i try to display the image for example using <img src={all.results.poster_path}/> the app crashes and with<img src={all.poster_path}/> nothing shows